# Android Startup process and Main Activity - Design Pattern

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have the following problem, and I would like to design the implementation to make sure I will not encounter any issues.

At application startup, I need to do one (and only one) server request to keep the phone up to date. Then I enter into the main activity.

My biggest issue is the Back button with Android, which can potentially bring back my stack to the very first activity, ie, the one that does server synchronisation.

I have thought of the following implementation:

1. I launched the Main activity straight away
2. In the `onCreate()` of the Main `Activity`, I launch the synchronisation process ... with some background logos, progress bar, etc etc...
3. Upon completion of the synchronisation, i call `finish()` function on my `Activity`.

Will I then return the `onCreate()`, or straight to `onResume()` of the main `Activity`?
Does this implementation make sense?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

to prevent your first `Activity` from being viewed again, you just need to add the following line to you `Activity` declaration

```
<activity 
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:noHistory="true" />
```

Using the `noHistory` tag will remove your `Activity` without the need to do it your self programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can continue doing the same but for the first activity where you do the synchronization thing, make it a noHistory Task. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Or in your First Activity, after you call `startActivity(MainActivity)` you can call finish() and by doing which your FirstActivity will be removed from backstack and then MainActivity will remain on top of the stack.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE

I mean to say is, let `FirstActivity` be your first activity and you start `MainActivity` from `FirstActivity`. After you call `startActivity()` in your `FirstActivity`, call `finish()` in the very next statement. This is completely acceptable.